# One thread is always running without a chance for other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Why the main thread is never executed? I thought that is I use `Thread.sleep(int value)` I give a chance to other threads to run, but this never happen.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Sook o = new Sook();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000); // Specially set to give a chance to the main thread to run
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t.run();

        System.out.println("<<<<<BACK TO MAIN >>>>>>"); // Never happens
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not call, t.run(), call t.start()

Just run will call the run method in the currently Thread.

Comment: Also, you mustn't swallow the `InterruptedException`. There should be a `return;` in the catch block.

Comment: Oh my God! What a mistake! Thank you very much.

Comment: @AndroidNoob, also you don't have to sleep or do something specifically to give time to other threads. The OS and the JVM will handle it for you. If you need finer control of how much time each thread consumes, use priorities. There is also the `yield()` method specifically to give time to other threads, but you probably will never need it either.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov I dont really see anything wrong with sleeping.  Thread priorities are one of the least portable/reliable set of functionalities  offered by Java. If he is spinning like that for ever you can imagine that even with OS scheduling that thread will be consuming too much of a single processor anyway.

Comment: @John, nothing wrong with sleeping itself. But the very purpose of creating a thread is to make it do something useful, right? So why sleep then? Of course, there is no point in just spinning either. But in most cases, thread spends most of its time blocked in something like Object.wait() or BlockingQueue.take() or some sort of I/O operation. If sleeping makes sense in a particular task, then of course it should be used. My point was just that it isn't necessary to give time to other threads.

Comment: I would argue that if you wanted to give time to threads you are better off using Thread.sleep(0) or Thread.yield() instead of thread priorities. The point I made was based soley on what he was doing in respect to giving some time to other threads.  It would be useful if your thread was continuously spinning like his is (regardless of why).